# How add separation only when needed?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, inline

How add separation only when needed between list element displayed inline with an new line is make when container width is changed?

For example:

```
<ul>
    <li>aaaaaa</li>
    <li>bbbbbb</li>
    <li>cccccc</li>
    <li>dddddd</li>
    <li>eeeeee</li>
</ul>
```

I would like to have the views above according to the parent's available width space, the '§' corresponding to the separation to be added and '|' the parent's border:

```
|  aaaaaa § bbbbbb § cccccc § dddddd § eeeeee  |
```

or

```
|  aaaaaa § bbbbbb § cccccc § dddddd  |
|               eeeeeee               |
```

or

```
|  aaaaaa § bbbbbb § cccccc  |
|      dddddd § eeeeee       |
```

or

```
|  aaaaaa § bbbbbb  |
|  cccccc § dddddd  |
|      eeeeeee      |
```

or

```
|  aaaaaa  |
|  bbbbbb  |
|  cccccc  |
|  dddddd  |
|  eeeeee  |
```

As Paulie_D replied that if I need to center the list, it would have to go through JavaScript, I restart the question by adding the JS in the tags.

I think it could be something like that in JS:

```
if (next_item exist AND next_item Y = current_item Y) then add the separation
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally did something in jquery that seems to work as long as the margins between the elements of the list are the same with or without seizure.

https://codepen.io/steveoriol/pen/gBvLZB

```js
$('.menu > li').bind('setseparation',function() {
    var nextitem = $(this).next('li');
    if (
      nextitem.length > 0 && 
      $(this).position().top == nextitem.position().top
      ) 
    {
      //console.log( $(this).position().top + ' == ' + nextitem.position().top);
      $(this).addClass( "separation" );
    }
    else $(this).removeClass( "separation" );
});

$( window ).resize(function() {
  $('.menu > li').trigger('setseparation');
});
```

```css
* {

  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

 ::before,
 ::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  width: 15%;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  text-align: center;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 .5em;
  position: relative;
}

li.separation:after {
  content: "§";
  position: absolute;
  right: -0.8em;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li>aaaaaa</li>
  <li>bbbbbb</li>
  <li>cccccc</li>
  <li>dddddd</li>
  <li>eeeeee</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally you'd need javascript but you could hack something with negative margins and `overflow:hidden`.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

 ::before,
 ::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  width: 30%;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  overflow: hidden;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 1em;
}

li:before {
  content: "§";
  margin: 0 0 0 -2em;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>aaaaaa</li>
  <li>bbbbbb</li>
  <li>cccccc</li>
  <li>dddddd</li>
  <li>eeeeee</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response super fast and works well, but only in case all is aligned to the left.
In my case (I forgot to specify it), I'd like to center everything, and this solution no longer works :-(

Comment: Then I'm afraid JS is your only option. CSS can't detect overflow or wrapping.

Comment: What if the content had a fixed width? Would the negative margin work then?

Comment: You mean that it is possible to delete or hide the separations of each first element of a new line in JS. How do you do that?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this is what you are looking for ?

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
}

li:before {
  content: '§ ';
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <body>



  <ul>
    <li>aaaaaa</li>
    <li>bbbbbb</li>
    <li>cccccc</li>
    <li>dddddd</li>
    <li>eeeeee</li>
</ul>

<//body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you have misunderstood the question.